# Retrieve Scheduled Task Trigger details via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Powershell script that pulls specific information about scheduled tasks from remote computers.  My goal to have this run weekly to export the information to keep documentation updated.  I have everything working except that the trigger information is generic **(System.Xml.XmlElement)** and I would like to have the summary that shows up when you open Task Scheduler **(At 6:50 PM every day - After triggered, repeat every hour for a duration of 1 day.)** come through.  The function I have so far is below.  I specifically need assistance with the Triggers.

```
function Get-TasktInfo {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param (
   [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,position=0,mandatory=$true)]$AllFolders
   )
PROCESS{
    foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
        if (($Tasks = $Folder.GetTasks(1))) {
            $Tasks | Foreach-Object {
                 $xml = [xml]$_.xml;
                New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                'Name' = $_.name
                'UserId' = ([xml]$_.xml).Task.Principals.Principal.UserID
                'Triggers' = $(If($xml.task.triggers) {ForEach($task in ($xml.task.triggers | gm | Where{$_.membertype -eq "Property"})){$xml.task.triggers.$($task.name)}})
                'Author' =  ([xml]$_.xml).Task.RegistrationInfo.Author
                'Description' = ([xml]$_.xml).Task.RegistrationInfo.Description
                'State' = switch ($_.State) {
                    0 {'Unknown'}
                    1 {'Disabled'}
                    2 {'Queued'}
                    3 {'Ready'}
                    4 {'Running'}
                    Default {'Unknown'}
                }
                'Actions' = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
                'Path' = $_.path
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
END{
    return $Tasks
}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for `'Triggers' = ([xml]$_.xml).Task.Triggers.ChildNodes|Out-String` ?

Comment: Thanks!! That gets me a lot closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: The ([xml]$_.xml).Task.Triggers.ChildNodes|Out-String gets me this "Repetition StartBoundary Enabled ScheduleByDay ---------- ------------- ------- ------------- Repetition 2014-01-31T09:02:00 true ScheduleByDay" is there a way to get this?  "At 9:02 AM every day - After triggered, repeat every 00:07:00 for a duration of 12 hours."